# Force TinyMCE to reload plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce, http-caching

I'm developing a TinyMCE plugin, however the changes I'm making to the plugin do not get loaded into TinyMCE after the first time it's loaded (It's getting cached). This is happening on both FF and Chrome.

If I search the cache in Firefox, I find a reference to the plugin's editor_plugin.js file with a cache expiry of 6 days 23 hours.

The only way I can get round this is to clear the cache on the browser every time I want to test a change - Anyone else get this behaviour? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: When I say the only way I can get round it is to clear the cache, this isn't actually true, I could obviously change the name space it gets loaded into each time, but that just seems ridiculous...

Answer (score 3):

To force reloading the cache on clients, tinyMce implements the solution with a cache_suffix. It will reload all the files if you change the suffix.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  cache_suffix: '?v=4.1.6'
});
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#cache_suffix

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way in Firefox to get rid of the chache on every new page load.
You need to install Firebug.
Go to the network tab and choose "deactivate browser cache".

Comment: So is this expected behaviour from TinyMCE then do you know? And what happens in a live system where you want a plugin to update before the cache expires?

Comment: This has nothing to do with tinymce. It is a purely browser related thing....In such a case the users will have to clear their cache manually if there is no possibility to clear it from a centralized point (like in enterprises).

Comment: @Thariama, "this has nothing to do with tinymce" : totally incorrect. TinyMce could just have a setting to prevent caching and it could load the plugin scripts with a random query parameter. This is just they did not ( and still don't ) care about how much time and effort a plugin developer spends by playing with the browser cache every time he changes sth.

Comment: @CagatayKalan: i agree

Answer (score 1):

Usually I *manipulate* the changed script's referring url, for example:

```
ed.windowManager.open({
    file : url + '/image.htm?v1',...});
```

The file name is not changed, but the script vill be reloaded at production time too.